# Documents and Media: Give a role the permission to define the permissions on files and folders

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA3 and the Documents and Media portlet. I created several roles in Liferay, one named "Documents-Admin". What I want is that a user with this role is able to create folders and files etc. and can change the permissions of these so that only specific users/roles have access to them.

So I changed the permissions for this role under Control Panel -> Users -> Roles and granted everything in Site-Administration -> Applications -> Documents and Media.

With this setting, a user with this role is able to open the permissions configurations of folders (even when he's not the owner). But the table only shows the roles "Users" and "Documents-Admin" - but there are 30 more. What do I have to do to see the full list of roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In control panel > Roles

Click on Documents-Admin role which you created and select define permissions.

And in that for **Role** you try giving **view** permissions or try giving there different permissions.

Comment: Could you be more concrete? As I said, i gave that role all permissions for the application "Documents and Media". That allows me open the permissions settings for a folder with that role, but the table does not contain any other role then mine and "guest"...

Comment: Yes Inside permissions settings your not getting other roles.right?

Comment: Right, got it. The view permission under roles - resource permissions is needed. Thank you very much!